# make multiple groups of images and paragraphs responsive inside a column

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, responsive

So I have multiple divs with images and another group of divs with p tags (only numbers) that make up an odontogram (a set of teeth with their corresponding numbers) inside a column which its length is 8 and then it is inside a boostrap card. Each image contains a div

Here is all the code https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/ExKqwXP
and here is a sample

```
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-md-8 odontograma">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <br>
            <div class="pieceRow1">
                <p class="pieza18" id="pieza18">18</p>
                <p class="pieza17" id="pieza17">17</p>
                <p class="pieza16" id="pieza16">16</p>
                <p class="pieza15" id="pieza15">15</p>
                <p class="pieza14" id="pieza14">14</p>
                <p class="pieza13" id="pieza13">13</p>
                <p class="pieza12" id="pieza12">12</p>
                <p class="pieza11" id="pieza11">11</p>
                <p class="pieza21" id="pieza21">21</p>
                <p class="pieza22" id="pieza22">22</p>
                <p class="pieza23" id="pieza23">23</p>
                <p class="pieza24" id="pieza24">24</p>
                <p class="pieza25" id="pieza25">25</p>
                <p class="pieza26" id="pieza26">26</p>
                <p class="pieza27" id="pieza27">27</p>
                <p class="pieza28" id="pieza28">28</p>
            </div>
            <div class="fila1 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="pieza18" id="img18"><img class="diente18" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>
                <div class="pieza17" id="img017"><img class="diente17" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza16" id="img17"><img class="diente16" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza15" id="img15"><img class="diente15" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza14" id="img14"><img class="diente14" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza13" id="img13"><img class="diente13" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza12" id="img12"><img class="diente12" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza11" id="img11"><img class="diente11" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 ml-3"></div>
                <div class="pieza21" id="img21"><img class="diente21" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza22" id="img22"><img class="diente22" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza23" id="img23"><img class="diente23" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza24" id="img24"><img class="diente24" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza25" id="img25"><img class="diente25" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza26" id="img26"><img class="diente26" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza27" id="img27"><img class="diente27" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-3"></div>

                <div class="pieza28" id="img28"><img class="diente28" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to put the class 'img-fluid' in the img but it makes them small and it doesn't make them responsive.
Is there a way to make number-image responsive inside the column with bootstrap or css?

Comment: hard to get something liek this full responsive. actually would be best to use a simple picture that will be responsive. Hoever if you want to do it at least desktop responsive, I would highly recommend to do it with a CSS-Grid.

Comment: but how can I use only one picture if I want it to display like the example? sorry maybe I'm not understanding, as for the css grid I will search

Comment: well dont create the ontrogramm with CSS, paint/create a picture of the ontrogram to be displayed. the problem is, you have 16 teeth in one column with a size of 42px. so by that alone you have 600px min-width. If you go below that, you have to seriosly downsize the images. Otherwise it wont stay full responsive

Comment: but the problem is that I have to manipulate the images like replace for another one but all blue, for exaple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you really want an Ontogramm done with HTML and CSS, instead of using a graphic/image then a grid could do that. This grid, however, will require a min-width of 720px to be displayed correctly. Below that, you're having issues solely based on the size. It should adapt to the screen size and expand to its full width by its own.

```css
body {
  min-width: 720px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(17, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- 1st Row -->
  <div>18</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div> 

  <!-- 2nd Row -->
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  
  <!-- 3rd Row -->
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  
  <!-- 4th Row -->
  <div>48</div>
  <div>47</div>
  <div>46</div>
  <div>45</div>
  <div>44</div>
  <div>43</div>
  <div>42</div>
  <div>41</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>31</div>
  <div>32</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>35</div>
  <div>36</div>
  <div>37</div>
  <div>38</div> 
  
  <!-- 5th Row -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>55</div>
  <div>54</div>
  <div>53</div>
  <div>52</div>
  <div>51</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>61</div>
  <div>62</div>
  <div>63</div>
  <div>64</div>
  <div>65</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 

  <!-- 6th Row -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  <!-- 7th Row -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  <!-- 8th Row -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>85</div>
  <div>84</div>
  <div>83</div>
  <div>82</div>
  <div>81</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>71</div>
  <div>72</div>
  <div>73</div>
  <div>74</div>
  <div>75</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```